# Add a new tab to Wordpress Plugin install Listing

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

When an user searches for a plugin from the WP Admin's Add Plugin area, I want to add a new tab(with a link to a page) next to the current tabs.

The location where I want the link is marked in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Looked for it @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus but in vain.

Is it allowed by WP ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the filter: **`"views_plugin-install"`** (see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/views_this-screen-id/)).

You can find it in [`/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L336) (currently) at line 226:

```
$views = apply_filters( "views_{$this->screen->id}", $views );
```

Use it like:

```
add_filter( 'views_plugin-install', 'my_filter', 10, 1 );

function my_filter( $views ){
    //Do your stuff
    return $views;
}
```

Comment: also see filters `install_plugins_tabs`, `install_plugins_nonmenu_tabs` and `install_plugins_table_api_args_{$tab}` in file specified.